# Can android acquire light frequency using light sensor? How?

Tags: android, frequency, light-sensor

Can android acquire light frequency using light sensor? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't get the light frequency. The only value returned by the light sensor is the brightness in Lux values

See [SensorEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html) for details. (Search for "lux" to find the right spot)

> Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
>
> values[0]: Ambient light level in SI lux units

Comment: yeah, that is the only returned value. But is there any other way to meet my needs, like using camera?

Comment: With a camera you could take a picture, analyze it and try to check the color temperature. I guess you might get some results but I wouldn't wonder if the accuracy is bad.

Comment: Sounds workable, i will research and try it. Thank you.